# CakePHP MilesJ Uploader plugin - upload via AJAX

Tags: ajax, cakephp, file-upload

I'm trying to use [MilesJ's Upload plugin for CakePHP](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader) to upload a file via AJAX.

```
$this->Uploader = new Uploader();
$this->Uploader->setup(array('ajaxField' => 'qqfile'));
$data = $this->Uploader->upload($this->Uploader->ajaxField);
```

But it is returning `false`.

I haven't found any mention on the FAQ about how to use AJAX. I just got to that code after reading from [this ticket](https://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader/issues/60). But I'm not sure this is how I'm supposed to use the plugin to handle AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. `ajaxField` must be passed when creating the object, not later using the setup().

```
$this->Uploader = new Uploader(array('ajaxField' => 'qqfile'));
$data = $this->Uploader->upload($this->Uploader->ajaxField);
```

This worked just fine.